# Переопределенный метод equals

Tags: java, equals

```
@Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        Animal animal = (Animal) obj;
        return this.name.equals(animal.name) &&
                this.hashCode() == animal.hashCode();
    }
```

Что происходит в четвертой строке? Поле name - String. Метод equals будет вызван рекурсивно, который переопределенный,  или вызовется метод из класса String? А если name будет Integer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Естественно,

> вызовется метод из класса String

---

> А если name будет Integer?

То все равно

```
this.name.equals(animal.name)
```

Comment: То есть к каждому экземпляра класса применяется метод описанный именно в его классе?

Comment: @sleeeep123 кхм, кхм ... А как по-другому?